# Running XPages Extension Library on local machine

Tags: xpages

I have installed XPages Extension Library on my local machine. It shows all the components in the Controls tab. But when I use any of the components in my XPage and run it in a browser it shows the following error:

`Cannot find the library com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library, required by the application <DATABASE PATH>`

In the Application Proprties, in Advanced tab inside XPage libraries both `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library` & `com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.library` are checked. Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE:** For installing extension library I used the file updateSiteOpenNTF-designer.zip. For installing it I went to My Widgets in my sidebar panel clicked on Menu for Options, selected "Configure widget from... > Features and Plugins on an Update Site"

Comment: This is described in the installation instructions

Comment: @stwissel: Your solution worked. But the words are bit confusing in the installation instructions - “...installing the updateSiteOpenNTF-designer.zip file into Designer **or** manually extracting the features and plugins from this zip to a physical location on the server file system (the domino\workspace\applications\eclipse subfolder under Domino root directory)...” - excerpt from readme.pdf. I guess insead of OR it should be AND.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naveen. This installs the Extlib only in Designer, not in the local preview engine. You have to copy the plug-in and feature directory, as outlined in the install instructions in the download, into [NotesData]/domino/workspace/applications/eclipse