# XPage plugin working in Lotus Notes but not Notes browser

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

I have created an extension library component but my XPages Extension Library is working on my local Notes Browser. If I run my XPage in notes itself it works fine.

When I run it in the browser I get the following error is thrown:

> Cannot find the library com.example.blank.library, required by the application /ForLearnCopy.nsf.

What does this mean, and how can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Is it running when you open it in your Notes client only?

Comment: Yes... But when I try to open in browser, It throws the mentioned error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramakumar,
check the documentation of the extension library. It shows nicely what you have to do to get a plugin working everywhere. There are 3 places:

- install using an update site in Notes client - to work in the Notes client. Usually ends in NotesData/workspace/applications
- install into NotesData/domino/workspace/applications (look for plugins/features folder there) - to make it work on the local browser preview
- in the Domino server (use the updatesite.nsf and the [right parameter](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Extension_Library_Deployment))

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

You have to install your plugin like a server plugin.

Have a look here:
[Running XPages Extension Library on local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053959/running-xpages-extension-library-on-local-machine)

Hope this helps
Sven

Comment: nice catch to spot the related question!