# Xpages extension library works in client but not browser on local

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am having an issue  with a local db and extension library.    If there are any extension library controls on the page I get the error `Cannot find the library com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library` in the browser but if the same page is displayed in the client.

That is really strange is that as long as no page had extension pages controls on them, then the page works fine as a standard XPage. But as soon as an extension library control is placed on any page, even pages without extension library controls get that error. In fact the error remains after removing any trace of extension library controls in the db.

Any idea of how to get extension pages XPages, in a local db,  in the browser when it works fine in the client?

Comment: This should resolve this your error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053959/running-xpages-extension-library-on-local-machine. This question seems to be duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the files in:

workspace\applications\eclipse\plugins  which is found in the data directory to

domino\workspace\applications\eclipse\plugins

which is found under the data directory.