# Running XPages with POI on a local machine

Tags: apache-poi, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I have installed POI 4 XPages by following the steps but i can't do the second step because i devellop my application locally so i tried to edit the file notes.ini located in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes

After opening the domino designer there is no POI4XPages tab and i tried from window >My widgets to publish the POI 4 XPages Integration in the catalog but i can't

after that i checked the plugins installed in domino designer but no apache poi plugins installed

Please help me ,what should I do to make this works ?

Best regards

Comment: what are the steps you take?

Comment: As Thomas wrote you need to let us know what you have done.
Check out this link how to install the extensionlib
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053959/running-xpages-extension-library-on-local-machine?rq=1

Comment: You should take a look at ExtLib install guide. It explains different install steps of ExtLib for Domino server and Designer client. I hope you will see the pattern.

Comment: Even if you get this working it won't be representative of the end user experience and will likely give you misleading results. Best practice is to develop against an instance of Domino installed locally to the same machine as Designer; that way you're as productive as possible because it removes network latency from the equation, but you're still testing against a real Domino server, instead of Designer's "preview" feature, which often gives misleading results.

Comment: Thomas i followed these steps :http://my.webgate.biz/poi/documentation.nsf/viewdoc.xsp?docid=installguide

Comment: Frantisek i installed extlib and it works perfectly due to copying plugins and features from C:\XPagesExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-853.20121217-1354\updateSiteOpenNTF    to    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data\domino\workspace\applications\eclipse but for poi 4 xpages I did the same thing but no poi4xpages plugin in the domino designer

Comment: Tim you're right I don't yet have the permission to work with the domino server of the entreprise so in the meantime i wanted  to do an example using POI 4 XPages