# HTTP error 404 when previewing XPages in a web browser after installing XPages Extension Library

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

After installing the XPages Extension Library v15 from [openNTF.org](http://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library) the required way I get an 404 Error when `previewing` XPages in a browser. Previewing XPages in Notes works fine.

[IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21327454) states an issue that you need to check the `Build Automatically` in `Project` menu item of Domoino Designer to avoid 404 Error. But that item is checked.

What do I miss ?

Comment: What resource responds with 404?

Comment: I am sorry I do not know exactly what you mean. The application which contains the XPage is of type .nsf . Anyway I am `previewing` the XPage via the Domino Designer.

Comment: Ah, local preview. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10054540/785061. Better yet: use a local server

Comment: Please confirm if the Problems pane displays any errors for the XPage you're trying to preview. If the XPage has never been built successfully, it's not available to be displayed. Also, verify port 80 is available for Domino Designer to preview on and, if not, use preferences to change the port. Also try previewing the demo database to confirm it's not an issue specific to your application.

Comment: As far I can judge the XPages always build successfully. There is no error reported. Also the XPages can be `previewed` in Notes perfectly.  And I changed nothing so far, except a new ExtensionLib installation from v14 to v15. In the meanwhile I copied the `feature` and `plugin` folder to the various path as recommended in this thread. But error 404 is still there.

Comment: In my Designer, Build Automatically doesn't work reliably. You might have to switch it off and then always use Project Clean.

Comment: Tried that too - no success yet ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed ExtLib on **server** too.

Restart task http on server.

Clean your project with menu Project/Clean. This way it gets rebuild completely.

If it's still showing 404 error then have a look at error.log file on server.

*Update:*

You pointed out in your comment that you use "Preview in Web Browser" without a server.

The local preview loads plugins from

```
<data-directory>/domino/workspace/applications/eclipse
```

Copy all ExtLib's features/plugins from

```
<prog-directory>/framework/shared/eclipse
```

into this directory and restart Notes Client & Domino Designer.

Comment: I am not running a server. I just use Domino Designer. Also before installation previewing XPages in a browser worked perfect.

Comment: OK. Did you try clean?

Comment: clean Project and save ... yes

Comment: sorry, I do not get the message for the second line : Copy `where from` - `where to` ?

Comment: From `<prog-directory>/framework/shared/eclipse` to `<data-directory>/domino/workspace/applications/eclipse` - content of folders `features`and `plugins`

Comment: Please check `Help / Support / View Log` and `Help / Support / View Trace` for error messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I guess it's better to reinstall Domino Designer and Notes completely to get rid of all the weired issues

Comment: What Knut describes for copying the ExtLib features/plugins to another folder, should have fixed the preview issue, as long as you restarted Designer afterwards