# Bootstrap in xpages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I have Domino Designer version 9.0.1 FP4 installed on my computer. I downloaded an nsf database with xpages and demo bootstrap. How much do I try to load any xpages the error below is displayed in the browser. The library org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.library is enabled in the xsp property file. Do I have to do any procedure for the bootstrap to work? Does it no longer come in the Domino Designer extension library?

Error 500
HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you receive an Error 500, to have a good chance of receiving a correct answer, please follow the instructions outputted to the console along with the error, and look in the logs in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder for more details. "Error 500" means "something went wrong". The logs it points to will tell you what went wrong.

One possible cause, is the OpenNTF version of the Extension Library will also need installing on the server you're running the demo bootstrap application on. If you're using Designer local preview, the location DDE installs the plugins for its own use is not the location Designer local preview requires. You'll need to manually copy the features and plugins files into the required location, which I believe is `<Notes>\osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins` and `<Notes>\osgi\shared\eclipse\features`.

Comment: Do I copy to the two directories you mentioned? But where do I copy the plugins?

Comment: Copy the plugins and features folders from the download into the same location, so the ....9.0.1.v_00_XX.... files are in the same location as the ...9.0.1.v_00_00... files. Alternative, you can copy them to [notesdata]\domino\workspace\applications\eclipse folder, as mentioned on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053959/running-xpages-extension-library-on-local-machine and blog post http://naveegator.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/installing-and-running-xpages-extension.html

Comment: Okay, but I did not understand one thing. According to the [article](http://linqed.eu/2014/11/10/bootstrap-in-xpages-now-part-of-the-extension-library/) , the bootstrap is now part of the Extension Library that comes with Domino and Domino Designer, correct? Do I still have to download a download and copy the files anyway?

Comment: No, you're mis-reading the article. The version of the Extension Library that came with Notes and Domino 9.0.1 (not changed in *fix* packs) was 9.0.1.v00_00. This did *not* include Bootstrap. That article is referring to Extension Library delivered via OpenNTF, specifically versions 9.0.1v00_10 onwards. They were not delivered via fix packs. However, Ext Lib 9.0.1v00_17 was rolled back into the core in *Feature* Pack 8, as 9.0.1v08_00.This is expected to continue to happen in future Feature Packs.

Comment: Note that I did not find the plugins for 9.0.1.v08_00 copied to the relevant location for Designer Local Preview to work. I hope there will soon be a license for developers to have a local development server. If at all possible, that is my recommended configuration for development.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is not part of the Extension Lib that IBM provides unless you install FP8. You have to get that feature pack 8 or get the Ext. Lib. from OpenNTF.

Are you trying to view the demo on the local web preview or on a server? If a server use the update site database to import in the Ext. Lib. from OpenNTF and set the notes.ini setting. If using a local web preview than you can copy the files like Paul mentioned.